# JWebBrowser NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jwebbrowser

I am trying to use JWebBrowser and I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/events/MouseListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.internal.NativeCoreObjectFactory.create(NativeCoreObjectFactory.java:36)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser.<init>(JWebBrowser.java:189)
    at com.js.summative.Main.<init>(Main.java:39)
    at com.js.summative.Runner.main(Runner.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

From what I could gather online, which was not much, I need to use `swt.jar` which I have found and implemented into my buildpath but that is not doing any good. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem. I was using the wrong `swt.jar`. If anyone is having the same issue, they can go to [this](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) site and get the latest swt. Also, the version of the JVM should be checked because the swt has to be the same as the JVM version. For example, 32-bit JVM requires 32-bit swt.

Comment: great find... and where would we get a x64 swt?

Answer (score 0):

and add `NativeInterface.initialize();` to main